# Wait for blocking collection (queue) to decrease in size in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue, event-driven

I'm working on  project with the following workflow:

**Part One:**

- Event arrives asynchronously and is queued in blocking queue, we'll call that **Q1**
- Thread picks up next available item from that queue
- Item ends up running {N} number of tasks in parallel
- Each task queues its result on a second queue, we'll call that **Q2**.
- When processing of item finishes, the next item is read off the queue.

**Part Two:**

- Another thread reads off of **Q2** one object at a time and works on the result

So, the problem here is, every item on the first queue ends up running a large number of tasks in parallel, and each task queues its result.  The second queue must be processed serially, one item at a time though, and it's getting flooded.

---

**My Question**

I need a mechanism that will make the thread processing **Q1** wait until the number of items in **Q2** is below a specific threshhold.  What's the best way to achieve this?  Is there any way to have an event driven solution rather than a polling solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using a `Queue<T>`, you can use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) for Q2.  If you set its [`BoundedCapacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287159.aspx), calls to `Q2.Add()` will block when the capacity is reached.  This will automatically throttle the processing of Q1, as the N tasks will begin blocking if they can't add to the final queue.

Comment: Cool; I already use blocking collections here so that's a minor change :)

Comment: I'll try it out and accept if it works.  This could be a good fix as it would stop my task processing {N} threads from returning until they could queue their result, which would stop more events from being processed in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you receive data in occasional floods, with long droughts during which Q2 can catch up. Have you considered simply limiting the number of concurrent threads spawned from Q1 by using a limited thread pool for these tasks?

I suspect you could benefit from multiple thread pools, if the job size is easily determined on arrival. You could have a small number of threads to process large jobs, and a large number of threads ready to process small jobs. Even a 3rd intermediate queue might be beneficial.

Comment: We use a thread pool already.  The problem is its pretty hard to judge how many threads to use.  Sometimes we'll receive 80k events that are all small and the system is fine (the last queue doesn't pile up because the results sets are small/upload quickly to our distributed cache).  Other times, we'll receive 100 events and it will hang because the results sets are massive and the upload takes forever.  So, limiting the pool outright makes it run worse when results sets are small, but does solve the problem of flooding when they're too big.  +1 though its a good solution given I provided :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems like a perfect example to be solved by `TPL Dataflow` library. If you are willing to try it, here's how it could work (this is very simple example of course):

```
TransformBlock<int, bool> transform = new TransformBlock<int, bool>(i => i > 5 ? true : false,
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });
ActionBlock<bool> resultBlock = new ActionBlock<bool>(b => Console.WriteLine("My result is : " + b),
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 10 });
transform.LinkTo(resultBlock);
```

You are defining a transform block which will make your transformation (this works as your `Q1`), you can set it's parallelism level to number of tasks you want to be used.

Then, you are creating second block (working as your `Q2`), which will have `BoundedCapacity` set and it's processing every message synchronously, invoking an action for each element. This block could be substituted by any other, like `BufferBlock` which would allow you to poll from it on demand.

Comment: I don't have time to play with this now, but it seems interesting; I'll try it another time :) Thanks man.